# Regular Expression for Replacing Content Not Inside HTML Tags

Tags: php, regex

I've got a function that helps to interlink pages within my site by scanning blog entries, news, and other items for certain core keywords.  It then replaces those keywords with a link to the corresponding page.

I'm running into a problem where some words that should not be replaced with links are.  For example, I have a summary tag in a few of my HTML tables that contains a small summary of the table content.  So for example, I might have a tag that looks like this:

```
<table width="500" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" summary="This table contains a list of all car parts in inventory along with their corresponding prices">
...
</table>
```

My function incorrectly replaces a keyword or phrase like "car parts" with a link.  How can I structure my replacement regular expression to NOT replace it in cases like this, but DO replace it should it appear within a paragraph or even within a cell in an HTML table.

Thanks in advance for any help and guidance!

EDIT:  Just to clarify, I'm using PHP to render my pages.  I'm using a str_replace() before the content is output as HTML to the page.  I want to be able to replace that with an ereg_replace() so that I replace the content only if it meets certain conditions (i.e. as explained above).  Sorry if this caused any confusion!

Comment: What is your current regex pattern?

Comment: It seems to be generally accepted that you shouldn't use regex in conjunction with arguably complex HTML rules.  Have you considered using an XML parser to identify the sections which you want to run the replace on?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified, I'll add an EDIT statement.  I'm using PHP to render the page output.  I would use the regex inside of a PHp ereg_replace() instead of using str_replace().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Don't use regexes to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use the PHP DOM:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($str); // Your HTML

//get all tds
$cells = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');

// Do stuff to the cells

//get all paragraphs
$paragraphs = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('p');

// Do stuff to the paragraphs

// Etc...
```

Comment: How do I handle odd cases?  For example, I want to replace the word car with a link but car is part of another sentence and the whole sentence contains a link.  I don't want to link it in that particular case, how can I grab it so it's smart enough to ignore that case?

Comment: Here is one solution:

    `while ($parentNode = $node->parentNode) { 
      /* Check if $parentNode is anchor and abort insertion if it is */ 
    }`

Alternatively, you could create an XPath query to find cells/paragraphs without anchors. For more information, see the [PHP DOM XPath docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).